# Select related documents in one query from Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Consider the following data structure:

```
[   
    {
        "id": "parent",
        "links":[{
                "href": "child"
            }]
    },
    {
        "id": "child",
        "links":[{
                "href": "grand_child"
            }]
    },
    {
        "id": "grand_child",
        "links":[]
    },
    {
        "id": "some-other-item",
        "links":[{
            "href": "anywhere"
        }]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to select all the documents related to the "parent" in a **single query** using Cosmos DB SQL?
The result must include parent, child and grand_child documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here the JSON array shown in OP is array of documents in your collection.

**NO, this can not be done using SQL API querying tools**. CosmosDB does not support joining different documents, even less recursively. [Joins in CosmosDB SQL are self-joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join).

But if you definitely need this to happen server-side then you can implement the recursive gathering algorithm by scripting it to a **[Used Defined Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs)**. Rather ugly though, imho.

I would suggest to **just implement this on client side**, single query per depth and merge the results. This also keeps nice separation of logic and data and performance should be acceptable if you correctly query all new links together in single query to avoid (1+N).

If your actual needs get much more complex on graph traversal, then you'd have to migrate your documents (or just links) to somewhere else capable of querying graphs (ex: **[Gremlin API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction)**).