# CosmosDB Find average time for message to complete

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need some help with a SQL query in Cosmos. I have to find the average time it takes a message to complete during a load test from the events stored in our DB.

So far I can get the start and end times like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT c.TimestampUTC WHERE c.Event = 'message-accepted') as StartTime,
(SELECT c.TimestampUTC WHERE c.Event = 'message-completed') as EndTime
FROM c
WHERE c.TrackingId = 'LoadTest' AND (c.Event = 'message-accepted' OR c.Event = 'message-completed')
```

But I get an error when I try to get the DateTimeDiff like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT c.TimestampUTC WHERE c.Event = 'message-accepted') as StartTime,
(SELECT c.TimestampUTC WHERE c.Event = 'message-completed') as EndTime,
DateTimeDiff("second", StartTime, EndTime) as TotalTime
FROM c
WHERE c.TrackingId = 'LoadTest' AND (c.Event = 'message-accepted' OR c.Event = 'message-completed')
```

I am stuck here because I need the difference to use the AVG function. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
Here is a sample of the data stored in Cosmos

```
{
  "PartitionKey": "LoadTest",
  "RowKey": "4ee9709f-c826-4a88-9d6f-240ba439eb1d",
  "TrackingId": "LoadTest",
  "Event": "message-accepted",
  "TimestampUTC": "2022-09-14T19:12:18.8358914Z"
}
```

And this is the error I am getting when trying DateTimeDiff:
"Failed to query item for container enginelog:
One of the input values is invalid."

It is not giving much info which is why I am looking for help, I am following the format for the function in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/datetimediff)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share sample data stored in database and error detail while executing the query. –

Comment: @RitikaNalwaya I added the edits to my post

Comment: This might be a case where you pull all related documents (based on some common correlation id that's repeated in every document), and then do the date-difference computation within your code. I don't think you're going to be able to do an aggregation on individual properties across multiple documents unless they are all the exact same property name (and then aggregating them in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per sample data shared in question, the assumption is that there are two different documents with Event property value "message-accepted" and "message-completed". As David mentioned, functions can't be used on data/properties available across separate document until unless property names are same.

In order to achieve what is required, you may need to write client-side code to recursively fetch the properties value from separate documents. Please refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074149/select-related-documents-in-one-query-from-cosmos-db)

Comment: Thanks for the details, I am writing this logic in our code now.